# MySQL 5.7.8 or higher is required to run Craft CMS Error

Tags: craft3, mysql

I'm extremely new to Craft CMS and having to ensure it can be ran from a Azure Virtual Machine. I have added, Apache, PHP and MySQL and the website does run on the server. However the issue occurs when I head to the Admin part of the site, where I get the error (title of this post).

All PHP extensions are installed as per the requirements.

[image]

The server has MySQL 8 on it and the database is on a different server also running MySQL 8.

[image]

It's worth noting that this works fine locally using XAMPP and I can access the /admin section.

Any ideas what I can be missing, perhaps I need install an additional package of the server or some sort of configuration?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.
Rich

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked that all the required PHP extensions are installed/loaded when you check phpinfo()?

https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/requirements.html#required-php-extensions

The error might not be about the MySQL server version but the fact that the required MySQL driver for PHP isn't loaded potentially.

You may also want to run the Craft server check, to confirm if everything is present: https://github.com/craftcms/server-check

Comment: Hi James, Thank you for your response. I have checked both of these, add we have all extensions added and the server checker comes back all clean and ready. 

I found that php7 was still installed on the server also, so I have removed this but now getting a timeout error when attempting to view the admin section.

Comment: After server reboot - getting the same error

Comment: @RichardGriffiths Just a thought, for Craft CMS 4 have you set the CRAFT_DB related environment variables? https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/config/db-settings.html#attributes.